# delphi component to animate show/hide controls during runtime

Tags: delphi

In Delphi I show/hide controls during runtime and it does not look good as controls suddenly appear or disappear , so any one know a component that can do the show/hide (using visible property) but with some sort of animation ?

thanks

Comment: Another thing you could attempt to do is to add blinking text to your labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give it a go with [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Only for WinControls, well, it doesn't look stunning anyway:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Button2.Visible then
    AnimateWindow(Button2.Handle, 250, AW_HIDE or AW_VER_NEGATIVE or AW_SLIDE)
  else
    AnimateWindow(Button2.Handle, 250, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE);
  Button2.Visible := not Button2.Visible; // synch with VCL
end;
```

**edit:** A threaded version to hide show multiple controls simultaneously:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    procedure AnimateControls(Show: Boolean; Controls: array of TWinControl);
    procedure OnAnimateEnd(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

implementation
  ..

type
  TAnimateThr = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    FHWnd: HWND;
    FShow: Boolean;
    constructor Create(Handle: HWND; Show: Boolean);
  end;

{ TAnimateThr }

constructor TAnimateThr.Create(Handle: HWND; Show: Boolean);
begin
  FHWnd := Handle;
  FShow := Show;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  inherited Create(True);
end;

procedure TAnimateThr.Execute;
begin
  if FShow then 
    AnimateWindow(FHWnd, 250, AW_VER_POSITIVE or AW_SLIDE)
  else 
    AnimateWindow(FHWnd, 250, AW_HIDE or AW_VER_NEGATIVE or AW_SLIDE);
end;

{ Form1 }

procedure TForm1.OnAnimateEnd(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FindControl(TAnimateThr(Sender).FHWnd).Visible := TAnimateThr(Sender).FShow;
end;

procedure TForm1.AnimateControls(Show: Boolean; Controls: array of TWinControl);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(Controls) to High(Controls) do
    with TAnimateThr.Create(Controls[i].Handle, Show) do begin
      OnTerminate := OnAnimateEnd;
      Resume;
    end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AnimateControls(not Button1.Visible,
      [Button1, Button2, Button3, Edit1, CheckBox1]);
end;
```

Comment: thats enough for me, I am not greedy :) - is this new API ? if so how I know about new windows API that supported inside Delphi -- Thanks alot

Comment: @user - Actually it exists since Windows 98. Winapi is huge, and even if Delphi does not have built-in support for something, you can probably find a port of it by someone else. I don't know a way to track changes in the api or Delphi, when you need something you get to figure it out. :)

Comment: @user - I noticed the 'AnimateWindow' function is of a synchronous nature, that is it doesn't return until an animation is finished. That might not look good if you need to animate a lot of controls at once. In that case consider unaccepting the answer to have more attention to the question.   BTW, I tried a threaded version.., it just doesn't work consistently...

Comment: Thanks alot Sertac , I forget that there are even free thread components for Delphi - Many Thanks - BTW how people here find time to help other people ?